Unable to access file in google colab
Getting the below error when I run the code:
with open('C:\\Users\\My Folder\\Downloads\\RAG for LLMs.pdf', 'rb') as file:
    # Create a PDF reader object
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
    # Get the number of pages in the PDF file
    num_pages = reader.getNumPages()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\My Folder\Downloads\RAG for LLMs.pdf'
How to address this error.

It's my understanding that google colaboratory is a cloud/hosted service, so of course it wouldn't have access to the files on your local computer...

Google Colab runs all on server and you have to upload files on this server. Or upload on your Google Drive and later you can mount Google Drive as folder on server.

Colab doc: External data: Local Files, Drive, Sheets, and Cloud Storage - Colab


You need to upload all your data to google drive.
Then inside google notebook attach your google drive to the colab session:

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')


After you can navigate inside /content/drive folder to your files:

!ls -lh /content/drive/

Another option is to upload the file directly into colab session

